# Notify User when a update is available for the installed app

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I want to notify user in an alert dialog that if my app has an update in the play store when the app is launched by user.

Is there any service to call and get the updates from play store of a particular app?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library that provides this functionality. You'll need your own server to host the version of code file it needs, but it is very easy to use. You can find it [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker), along with documentation.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it:
 1. Build  a webservice and have your version number in a database. 
 2. On application start up check your database if version is updated.
 3. If updated, do show a notify dialog.

Comment: Creating an entire Web service and database mechanism is overkill for this. A simple text file will do the job.